# use of unassigned local variable fedTax and netPay in last two lines

Tags: c#

```
if(hoursWorked > base_hours)
{
    basePay = hourlyPayRate * base_hours;
    overtimeHours = hoursWorked - base_hours;
    overtimePay = overtimeHours * hourlyPayRate * overtime_rate;

    grossPay = basePay + overtimePay;
    fedTax = grossPay * 0.15m;
    netPay = grossPay - fedTax;
}
else
{
    grossPay = hoursWorked * hourlyPayRate;
}

textBox4.Text = grossPay.ToString("c");
textBox5.Text = fedTax.ToString("c");
textBox6.Text = netPay.ToString("c");
```

use of unassigned local variable fedTax second last line.
use of unassigned local variable netPay in the last line.

Comment: You only assign `grossPay` in the `else` branch, `fedTax` and `netPay` are only assigned in the `if` branch...

Comment: so what should i write in else??

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing when you declared those two variables, you didn't initialize them to anything. So if your else statement executes, they remain uninitialized.

You could just initialize them to "" during your declaration to avoid this (assuming that won't harm your functionality), but in this case I think you're wanting to just copy

```
fedTax = grossPay * 0.15m;
netPay = grossPay - fedTax;
```

into your else block as well.